# For a W-2, is there a threshold for box 1 below which I don't have to report the income?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

My wife received a (correct) W-2 where box 1 is $0.23.

When TurboTax reviews for errors, it tells me that I have a W-2 without a box 1 value specified (I guess because it rounds it down to $0) and won't allow me to e-file.

Is there some threshold for W-2 reporting requirements? Can I just remove this W-2 from my return?

Links to official documentation appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

For the federal forms - you can just remove it, and worst case you'd get a rounding error in case she has other W-2. Just round up all of them to be on the safe side. If that's the only W-2 she has - then you can safely round down to 0 (see [instructions to form 1040](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040.pdf&ei=vGI8T67FE-TZiQKvjqmHAQ&usg=AFQjCNHSKMBWCzrIuejcLK7rh7YGL_CFDA), "Rounding Off to Whole Dollars" on page 19).

Some states require filing a form which lists all the W-2's received (for example New York State form IT-2) - then list it as it is and make sure the totals match.

Don't forget to attach the relevant parts to the relevant returns.

I'm not sure if you can just "ignore" and omit the W-2, I believe you must attach it to your return. If you cannot force Turbo Tax to e-file it (try editing the forms directly and entering the value there), then you can either write it as $1 (and pay some for tax perhaps) or paper-file it (and pay much more for mailing). I'd write down $1 and be done with it.

Comment: +1 to just round it up. Nobody's gonna send you to jail for paying an extra 30 cents in taxes, and much less likely to set off flags for none listed at all.

Comment: Note that if you round, you need to round throughout your return.